# Silently create conda virtual environment in Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

Is it possible to silently create a conda virtual environment for Python version 3.6.8
in Windows 10, from an anaconda (cmd) prompt, using either of these commands modified? (or any other way):

```
conda create -n py368 Python=3.6.8 /S

conda create -n py368 Python=3.6.8 /Q

call conda create -n py368 Python=3.6.8 /S

call conda create -n py368 Python=3.6.8 /Q
```

Upon running either of the above commands, Anaconda seem to read /S or /Q as a missing package,
instead of the silent keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Windows syntax for a program that is fundamentally a Linux-based application that has been ported to Windows.  Rather than using a `/S`, you need to use either `-y` or `--yes`.

Also, the package specification must come at the *end* of the command line.  So, the syntax that you are looking for is something like the following.

```
conda create -n py368 --yes Python=3.6.8
```

or, if you don't want to see any output,

```
conda create -n py368 --yes Python=3.6.8 2> $null > $null
```

**Warning**, in some versions of `conda`, such as `conda 3.7.3`, and possible `conda 3.7.2`, the auto-accept command option (`-y`/`--yes`) was ignored, and the examples above would hang while waiting for user-input.  In the broken versions of conda, the following example also doesn't work:

```
echo y | conda create -n py368 --yes Python=3.6.8
```

**Workaround**:
This has worked in all versions of conda that I have tested it in.

```
conda config --set always_yes True
conda create -n py368 --yes Python=3.6.8
```